# how to provide login username and password to ffmpeg?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

how can i provide username and password to ffmpeg to enable it to write data to some folder in ftp server?
the folder is protected by password and if possible i dont want to remove that password. so, can i simply just pass the password to ffmpeg? or is there any other solutions?

example of ffmpeg process to create thumbnail from video file

```
string thumbpath, thumbname, videofile;
videofile = "Video Source path";
thumbpath = "thumbnail path";
thumbname = thumbpath + "20120910160600.mjpeg";

string thumbargs = "-i \"" + videofile + "\" -vframes 1 -s 60*30 -ss 00:00:00 -f image2 \"" + thumbname + "\"";

Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");
process.StartInfo.Arguments = thumbargs;

process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

New Learner, 
Please guide me....

Comment: Is the ftp server running on the same machine as the web application?

If so you will have to set up the folder permissions on the "thumbpath" so that the ASP.NET process have write access to the folder. Alternatively you will have to use impersonation in order to run the ffmpeg process as a user that has write permission on the folder.

Comment: can u tell me more about impersonation? i found that i need to add something in web.config. But do i need to add something in ffmpeg to make ffmpeg process able to use that impersonation setting? or just modify the web.config and it enough.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have the possibility to set permissions on the folder(s) you are making ffmpeg write to, you can set up the account that the ASP.NET process is running under to have write access. You can control which account ASP.NET is running under either by configuring the app pool or by [using impersonation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158). This is the easiest approach.

Application level impersonation is done by putting this in the web.config:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```

This will cause the web application to run as the provided user all the time.

If you want to tighten security, you can make only the process that is running ffmpeg run under a user with write access. You can achieve this using code level impersonation (as described in the impersonation link above).

Regardless of the approach ffmpeg shouldn't need to know which user it's running as.